# How to use RediSearch libraries from my C++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake, redisearch

I am developing a project in C++ that utilizes RediSearch. I would like to be able to call RediSearch functions in a form similar to `#include <redisearch/document.h>` utilizing CMake without having to alter the RediSearch project.

This question should be applicable to using CMake with any external CMake project, but all I have found is very specific to a certain set of projects or simply do not work.

### Attempts

I have attempted to use `ExternalProject` such as in [this project](https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject), using Config files and `find_package()` as in [this project](https://github.com/pabloariasal/modern-cmake-sample), directly using `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries`, linking to the src/ folder directly, etc.

I have also tried including the following lines in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(RS_INCLUDE_DIR libs/RediSearch/src)

set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-I${RS_INCLUDE_DIR} -Wall -g -fPIC -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

include_directories(${RS_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

but receive the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/prjct.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `RedisModule_Init':
....
collect2: error: 1d returned 1 exit status
....
```

### Resulting errors include but are not limited to:

- Not being able to locate the package when using `find_package` (as described in the aforementioned projects) and presenting an error such as:

  - ```
    CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.13.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137
    Could NOT find RediSearch (missing: RediSearch_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/cmake-3.13.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    cmake/FindRediSearch.cmake:27 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:48 (find_package)
    ```
- If CMake does not give any errors, then on make: `redisearch/document.h: No such file or directory`

### To detail my project structure:

```
prjct
| src/
| | main.cpp
| include/
| | prjct/
| | | myheader.hpp
| libs/
| | RediSearch/     <- As git submodule
| cmake/
| | prjctConfig.cmake.in
| CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to, from any `src/` file such as `main.cpp`, utilize RediSearch (or for that matter any project which would be built with CMake) in the form `#include <redisearch/document.h>`. I do not want to alter RediSearch files or configuration at all - everything should be conducted through my project.

*Note: I am using cmake version 3.13.3*

Comment: Please show what you have attempted with `CMake`. And explain what happened.

Comment: You want to use it as a library or over network?

Comment: @drescherjm as explained in my post I attempted the methods described [here](https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject) and [here](https://github.com/pabloariasal/modern-cmake-sample) in addition to directly including the project through the use of `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer yes, as a library. I have edited the post with an example of the desired project structure.

Comment: It relies a lot on redis proper and most of the code assumes it is running inside a redis instance. Unless your code is also a redis module, it will be painful.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer would it therefore be more feasible to write a separate c++ client library such as [JRediSearch](https://github.com/RedisLabs/JRediSearch)?

Comment: Most certainly!

Comment: You could probably just utilize hiredis or a similar existing C library. A proper C++ client would be nice, though :)